# How to handle questions about the (SharePoint) Dev Stack

Tags: discussion

Re: [how to implement the lastest angular 2 version with sharepoint hosted add-ins](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/190305/how-to-implement-the-lastest-angular-2-version-with-sharepoint-hosted-add-ins)

With the new SharePoint Framework and all other goodies we will get more and more of these
**non-SharePoint-*but-related*** questions.

People will run into all sorts of trouble... NPM questions, TypeScript questions, IDE config config questions, Angular (like the one above) library questions.

**Do we need a `SharePoint DEV stack` tag?**

**Do we need a '*One answer to rule them all*' answer?** pointing to a FAQ

**Does SharePoint.StackExchange have a future?** with Microsofts [Network.Office.com/SharePoint](https://network.office.com/t5/SharePoint/) as open alternative?

### Update #1

Microsoft has added 3 tags:

- **SPFX** - [info](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tags/spfx/info) -> [Newest posts](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spfx?sort=newest&pageSize=50)
- **SPFX-Tooling** - [info](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tags/spfx-tooling/info) -> [Newest posts](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spfx-tooling?sort=newest&pageSize=50)
- **SPFX-WebParts** - [info](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tags/spfx-webparts/info) -> [Newest posts](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spfx-webparts?sort=newest&pageSize=50)

Answer (score 8):

Microsoft will point to SharePoint Stack Exchange for developer related questions. This will be the main source for dev Q&A for SPFx, the new O365 Network are not good enough and will never be as good as this system.

Comment: Cool, they close Yammer, open Network, then point the majority of questions to a 3rd party

Answer (score 6):

As Wictor says, Microsoft's engineering team have said they will monitor SharePoint Stack Exchange for questions about SharePoint Framework, specifically those tagged #spfx, #spfx-tooling and #spfx-webparts. Of course those tags didn't exist, so I have created them. I think #spfx-tooling covers the case suggested by the OP.

This is good for this site, but unfortunately dev.office.com still links to Stack Overflow with the very generic ms office tag.

Regarding Office 365 Network, that is a discussion site. StackExchange is specifically a "knowledge exchange" and a fundamental difference is that it is questions and answers only, which is why we shut down chatty discussions (a common misunderstanding by people new to the site). So they really serve two different purposes.

Answer (score 5):

I think we should handle it as we have done so far. We have tags for all sort of not even close to SharePoint coding, such as [jquery](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jquery) or the tag [java-api](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java-api). Instead of disqualifying questions based on coding language we should look at it the other way around. If you try to do anything with SharePoint, in any existing or future programming language, it is a valid question.

As Robert mentioned in his comment, the question you’re referring to is too broad and not off topic. This means that you can ask how you should update a list item in SharePoint using any JavaScript library, Lisp or COBOL for whatever reason. Key takeaway here is as always not asking questions that aren’t specific enough.

A SharePoint DEV stack tag would be too wide. It is valid for any of our coding question and doesn’t make the question clearer.

When we discuss Frodo and his quest to carry the one ring to rule them all into Mordor, I think it’s a bad idea. Maybe if the [Documentation beta on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sharepoint/topics) is a hit the documentation may spread to other Stack Exchange sites such as ours. As of now SharePoint is one of the documentation topics...

If SP.SE is valid when MS has published its new network? So far we are working alongside social TechNet, and both have its place and time. The Office Network, currently in preview, is more a discussion type forum or Blog comment forum to be any real competition. Here we are still very rigid about Question and Answer. Nothing else. This is our USP which hasn't been copied yet.

Comment: Admin Eric Alexander closed the mentioned question... So "as We have done" is kinda like my first marriage

Comment: To be fair, it is closed as too broad, not of-topic

Comment: So if you specify the question in more detail @Danny'365CSI'Engelman, it can be reopened. Remember to be specific and not ask questions of an entire framework.

Comment: It is not my question. I am thinking ahead of the chaos that might happen after Ignite.

Comment: The original question was "Hi I'm trying to implement angular 2 within a sharepoint hosted app, I followed the scot hillier's article Build a SharePoint Add-In with Angular2 and TypeScript and Technical Samvaad's article Create SharePoint app for SharePoint 2013 using Angular2 with TypeScript but they are a little old now and I'm having a lot of errors, so, do somebody know where can I find some more new info about it or how can i approach that?" It was too broad. It is about an add-in so it is on topic, but we have to take care and look at these closely, same w/jQuery, etc.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I've updated my answer to make it more complete.